# How install php 5.6 in cloud 9?

Tags: php, cloud9-ide

I am using IDE cloud 9. using version there 5.5.9. But I need 5.6. I cant undestand how me install verison php 5.6. Wich commands I need use. Can you help me **step by step** how? Thank you

Comment: Cloud9 is simply an Ubuntu 14.04 machine so any guide that applies to it will apply to Cloud9. https://www.dev-metal.com/install-setup-php-5-6-ubuntu-14-04-lts/ should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never really used Cloud9 before. So, you might want to take a look at this https://community.c9.io/t/phpbrew-on-php-workspaces/621/2